# How to upload image file using cgi program written in c language?

Tags: c, cgi

I wanted to upload a jpeg image file on the server.I have a GoAhead web server which supports only cgi c program as a serverside handeling.

Can any one know how to handle http posted image file in program witten in cgi in c language?

Comment: CGI? With C? I'd suggest changing providers. If they can't even provide php or perl (or any other scripting language), they shouldn't be providing at all.

Comment: i must have to use c as this is embedded world.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get POST data just read stdin.  Environment variable CONTENT_LENGTH tells you how much to expect but of course you need to make your code robust against whatever a potentially malicious user can throw at you.

Comment: Yes i can get POSTED data using CONTENT_LENGTH but while uploading using multi-part browser adds multipart boundry and some headers.Do you know how to remove that boundry?

Answer (score 0):

The GoAhead web server has a file upload filter for this purpose. The upload filter receives the uploaded file and saves it to disk. It then sets some request variables describing the upload. Those variables are accessible via CGI or via action functions or JST templates.

There is an example in test.c. Search for uploadTest().

See: https://github.com/embedthis/goahead/blob/master/test/test.c

Comment: Link is broken. It says not found.